# My Mac always showed this notification "QGIS 3.12 (QGIS 3.10) can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software"

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, installation, macos

I am doing dialectology, and I was trying to install QGIS 3.12 (and QGIS 3.10 before) to use it in my study. Every time I opened the software my Mac always showed this notification "QGIS 3.12 ( QGIS3.10) can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software".

I also tried installing Python 3.8 hoping it would work, but it didn't and I received the same message above.

How can I install and use the software so that I can start learning the software?

Comment: Mac always ask you to decide would you activate software from unknown source. Probably you dont gave access

Comment: Right click (or press control and left click) and choose open from the menu. You will get a message warning but will be able to click open to start the installation

Answer (score 16):

After you try and open QGIS and get the error, you need to open MacOS "System Preferences" and select "Security & Privacy". Click "Okay" to dismiss the error, and you should now see an option under "General" to run the program below the "Allow apps downloaded from:" section.

Comment: Where to click "Okay"?

Comment: @Dims, I had to first change to "App Store," then the "Open Anyway" option appeared. Step here, https://imgur.com/a/PUYbVBX