# Difficulty downloading QGIS on Apple

Tags: qgis, apple

Every time I download QGIS on my MacBook Air and try to open the application I receive a message that reads, "QGIS can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software," along with a sub-message that complains about the software needing to be updated.  This does not make sense considering I downloaded the newest version.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, how did you combat it?

Comment: Have you checked the bug reports?

Comment: Where did you download it from?

Comment: Here is a similar [question & solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359610/my-mac-always-showed-this-notification-qgis-3-12-qgis-3-10-cant-be-opened-be), can you try that?